# Delte Specifc lines from file in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which uses a xml schema. That looks like this:

```
    <maplayer simplifyAlgorithm="0" minimumScale="0" maximumScale="2500" simplifyDrawingHints="0" readOnly="0" minLabelScale="0" maxLabelScale="1e+08" simplifyDrawingTol="1" geometry="Point" simplifyMaxScale="1" type="vector" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="1" simplifyLocal="1" scaleBasedLabelVisibilityFlag="0">
      <id></id>
      <datasource>port=1521 user=test_user password=test_passwd</datasource>
      <keywordList>
        <value></value>
      </keywordList>
      <featformsuppress>0</featformsuppress>
      <editorlayout>generatedlayout</editorlayout>
      <widgets/>
      <conditionalstyles>
        <rowstyles/>
        <fieldstyles/>
      </conditionalstyles>
    </maplayer>
  </projectlayers>
  <properties>
    <Variables>
      <variableNames type="QStringList">
        <value>paswd</value>
        <value>user</value>
      </variableNames>
      <variableValues type="QStringList">
        <value>5zdgf</value>
        <value>dgdgdgfdg</value>
      </variableValues>
      </Variables>
    <customproperties>
    <property key="labeling/textColorR" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/textTransp" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/upsidedownLabels" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/useSubstitutions" value="false"/>
    <property key="labeling/wrapChar" value=""/>
    <property key="labeling/xOffset" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/yOffset" value="0"/>
    <property key="labeling/zIndex" value="0"/>
    <property key="variableNames"/>
    <property key="variableValues"/>
  </customproperties>
```

So I wanted to use python to delte the password and user part as well as the variables parts.
I use the following code:

```
import re

with open('C:\myfile.txt') as oldfile, open('C:\myfile_withoutPW.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    oldText = oldfile.read()
    noPass = re.sub(r'(password=).*?(?=\s) ', '', oldText.rstrip())
    noPass_noUser = re.sub(r'(user=).*?(?=\s) ', '', noPass.rstrip())
    # fehlt noch
    newText = re.sub(re.escape(r'<property key="variableNames"/>'), '', noPass_noUser.rstrip())
    newText = re.sub(re.escape(r'<property key="variableValues"/>'), '', newText.rstrip())
    newfile.write(newText)
```

This works, but not completly as I wanted it to, it deltes the parts but it leaves empty lines, like:

```
 <property key="labeling/wrapChar" value=""/>
        <property key="labeling/xOffset" value="0"/>
        <property key="labeling/yOffset" value="0"/>
        <property key="labeling/zIndex" value="0"/>


      </customproperties>
      <blendMode>0</blendMode>
      <featureBlendMo
```

How can i solve this to completly delte those lines/parts form my txt file?

Comment: `if newText.strip(): newfile.write(newText)` ?

Comment: Your xml doesn't match your code. For instance, no `<property key-"..."/>`.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the formatting, or are you ok with any modification?

Comment: [**Do not use regex to parse HTML/XML or any other form of a structured (irregular) data!**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7553525)

Comment: @tdelaney: the xml is very long so i tried to make a excertp. It adjusted the code a bit.

Comment: @viraptor: I would like to preserve the formating. So that in a "new" file only those lines are missing.
There are multiple instances of those lines i want to delete in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Processing xml with regex is risky. Suppose a property element is on more than one line. An alternative is to use Extensible Stylesheet Transforms (XSLT). I don't know all of your requirements so tried to match your example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- pretty print output -->  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- strip unwanted elements and attributes -->  
  <xsl:template match="datasource|Variables|@user|@password"/>

  <!-- pass everything else through -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- start tranform at the root -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Its not good practice but for my purpose its good to have more matches because there are many instance i want to delete form the file.

Comment: Potentially... the match gets all instances of its target and if you perform the same action for each thing you match then the only advantage to multiple match lines is readability.

Answer (score 0):

This seems workable for the output

```
(?mi)((?:password=|user=)[^\n]*$|\<property key=\"variableNames\"\/\>\n|\<property key=\"variableValues\"\/\>\n)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/64),,, in which newline `\n` is added to some parts of the regex so that `avoid creating empty line`.

In python, it may be like this

```
ss=""" copy&paste your string in this area """

regx= re.compile(r'(?mi)((?:password=|user=)[^\n]*$|\<property key=\"variableNames\"\/\>\n|\<property key=\"variableValues\"\/\>\n)')
print(regx.sub('',ss))
```

And if you want `remove empty lines` created from deleting matched strings, then you can try this regex for matching empty lines in your text.

```
(?m)^\s*$\n
```

Thus, it is applicable to your script by inseting this line.

```
newText = re.sub(r'(?m)^\s*$\n','',newText)
```